# Multiple calls to put() method when updating ndb on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2, app-engine-ndb

I have a web app on GAE which uses a ndb database where each entity has as properties user informations and two string, the Entity class is like the one below

```
class UserPlus(ndb.Model): 
user = ndb.UserProperty()
dogName = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
catName = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
```

The Main Page check if there's already an entity corresponding to that user, and if yes displays the value of the strings `dogName` and `catName`.

Then there's a form where users can update the values of `dogName` and `catName` . This performs a POST request to another page, the method below update the entiy

```
    def post(self): 
    currentUser = users.get_current_user()
    up = UserPlus.query(UserPlus.user==currentUser).get()
    up.dogName = self.request.get('dog_name')
    up.catName = self.request.get('cat_name')
    weatherUser.put()
    self.redirect('/')
```

But when I'm redirected to the Main Page, the values of `dogName` and `catName` are not updated until I refresh the page. I found that by calling the `put()` method two times instead of one, in the same position, this doesn't occur anymore, but I don't have clear why.

Am I doing something wrong or it's how ndb is supposed to work?

Comment: How does your main page get the user's page?  If it's a query, you are probably running into "eventual consistency".

Comment: Wow, the code is incorrectly formatted (won't run), I edited it and my edit got rejected :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Guido suspects and bossylobster/Fred Saur answered on my old question here - [Should I expect stale results after redirect on local environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773892/should-i-expect-stale-results-after-redirect-on-local-environment) - most likely eventual consistency problem.

Comment: Thanks kevin and Guido. In fact was an eventual consistency problem, as suggested on the question you linked, using an **ancestor query** fixed the problem